# Update activity time on concurrent connections

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, azure

I have a api and on each request to this api i save/update the user activity.

But the problem is, when there is 5 concurrent connections to the api from the same user, i get this:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_user_act'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'user_activity
>
> The duplicate key value is (2015-06-11, 76146, 1). The statement has
>   been terminated.*

I have this sql:

```
if not exists (select 1 from user_activity where user_id = @UserNr and stat_date = CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE))
   insert into user_activity(user_id, stat_date, start_date, end_date)
VALUES
(@UserNr, GETUTCDATE(), GETUTCDATE(), GETUTCDATE())
ELSE
   UPDATE user_activity set end_date = GETUTCDATE() where user_id = @UserNr and stat_date = CAST(GETUTCDATE() AS DATE)
```

I use ADO.NET and a SP to update the user activity. I think this sql is running at the same time, and the first request is saved, and the other 4 get this error.

What can i do to fix this?

UPDATE:
We using Azure SQL, v12 for this. *(We have 1-1,5 m connections to this api / day)*

Comment: What RDBMS and version?  Many have a [`MERGE` statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)).  The other thing to do would key the table by the combination of user id and timestamp (log each row separately, don't update them - although table may get large).  Or just cache the information in your application, and write to the DB if you don't see them for a while (DB writes are slow by comparison).

Comment: We use Azure SQL v12

Comment: You have a composite primary key. It needs to change if you want to do it like this. That is the first thing. The second is to use a MERGE instead of the if statement.

Comment: ok, but if i remove the composite primary key, i will get a lot of rows with the same information? We even save the online time in this table for the user so we can se, each day, how long a specific user has been online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck!  Azure SQL uses SQL Server, [which supports `MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx):

```
MERGE User_Activity AS target
USING (SELECT @UserNr, GETUTCDATE()) AS source (userNr, rightNow)
      ON (target.userId = source.userNr)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
     UPDATE SET end_date = source.rightNow
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (user_id, stat_date, start_date, end_date)
            VALUES (source.userNr, source.rightNow, source.rightNow, source.rightNow)
```

(not tested - no sample data)

---

Note, though this solves this particular issue, I agree with @The Bojan - you have a table with a multi-part key.  Probably what you should do is change your table to look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE User_Activity (userId INTEGER,
                            lastSeenAt DATETIME2)
```

... and just `INSERT` to it (and don't use any transactions).  At the end of each day you can easily roll up all the records into your current table, then clear it out.

Comment: Thanx, works perfect. But the best way is maybe to save each request and the day after calculate the statistics for the user?

Comment: @mrcode - Maybe, you'd need to do testing.  At minimum, it would enable you to not need transactional locks on the table (and if each user is spawning lots of concurrent entries, that could be a bottleneck).  Adding 1.5 mil rows to a table is nothing, especially because you won't need an index for it.  Writing to a db is slow (comparatively) - you may also want to try buffering and writing in bulk.  Or keeping the table in memory/application code.  In general, updating aggregates on-the-fly is more problematic than building it off of the complete stats.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Transactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx) in your SP to avoid the SQL instructions to be mixed up between concurrent executions and to ensure the check from your `IF` statement is getting the correct data for its check everytime

Comment: Yes, but this would require complete serialization of (writes to) the table.  Expensive, and a major bottleneck.

Comment: What would be a better solution for this, then?

Comment: depends on RDBMS, and intended table use.  Constantly updating the same row in the table is likely to be a large pain regardless.